# Does a collection have less details than a single resource?

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

I am wondering if this is correct or should be avoided?

**GET /products/**

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "phone",
    "price" : "10.00 GBP"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "car",
    "price" : "1000.00 GBP"
  }
```

**GET /products/1**

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "phone",
    "colour" : "blue",
    "memory: "2GB",
    "storage": "32GB",
    "connectivity" : "3G/4G",
    "price" : "10.00 GBP"
  }
```

The collections products does not return all the details about a single product but when retrieving the single product you can see all the details.

Is this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not wrong. In fact, you can use collections to give an "overview" of your entities, while the actual details can be found within the entities themselves. Normally, you also provide a link to the given entity in that case.

However, there is a downside: what constitutes an "overview". For one view, it might be enough just to display the name and the price, but another overview might other details like color etc. IN the first case, fetching the collection would be enough, in the latter, you must download each entity separately to fetch the color. Normally, the collection is "enriched" with the color so you don't have to anymore, but very (very!) soon, it would mean you are just returning all data from the entity in the collection anyway.

It's possible to overcome this by using the query string for filtering on WHAT you want to return (for instance:  `GET /articles?page=5&limit=10&fields=memory,name,colour,storage`, which would make it more dynamically and allows you to serve any detailed view out there, including mobile devices with limited bandwidth etc.

Comment: Absolutely agree with you. That's exactly what I was thinking. Thank you very much!

Comment: I like most of your answer, but this part: "Normally, you also provide a link to the given entity in that case." I disagree with that. I think you **HAVE TO** do that (in every case). As REST works purely based on HATEOAS its otherwise impossible for clients to operate with only one entity of that collection e.g.read the other fields or do the CRUD methods on it.

Comment: I agree, but sending links will only make sense if the given element is indeed a resource on itself. This is not always the case, nor is it always necessary. An example could be a list of countries for instance). It might be   possible that these countries have additional information and could be resources by itself, but it could also be a simple list of (accepted) countries within your API, where by themselves the countries form a collection, but not separate resources.